# Test for arbitrary-speed curve lying on a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

My textbook, ONeill's Elementary Differential Geometry, gives as an exercise the following test function to determine if a unit-speed curve lies on a sphere. If the test function is constant then the curve lies on a sphere. For a later exercise, we are invited to extend the test function so that it applies to arbitrary-speed curves. The prescription given is to multiply the derivative in the original formula by the speed of the curve. I tried that with a test curve that I am pretty confident lies on a sphere. But the results do not check out; the test function is not constant. I would like to know the above-stated prescription for taking into account arbitrary speed is as simple as I have suggested.

The test function for unit-speed curves is $\rho^2+(\rho^\prime\sigma)^2$, where $\rho$ is the inverse of the curvature, $\sigma$ is the inverse of the torsion, $N$ is the principal normal and $B$ is the binormal.

For the speed, I use $\nu=||\frac{d\alpha}{dt}||$. So for the modified test function I get $\rho^2+(\nu\rho^\prime\sigma)^2$

My curve that I believe lies on a sphere is $\alpha(t)=t/\sqrt{t^2+1}, cos(t)/\sqrt{t^2+1}, sin(t)/\sqrt{t^2+1}$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it lies on a sphere, $||\alpha-C||^2$ is constant. $\rho=1/\kappa$, $\sigma=1/\tau$.

$\nu$ is the speed.

$(\alpha-C)\cdot T=0$

$\alpha^\prime\cdot T+(\alpha-c)\cdot T^\prime=0$

$\nu=||T||^2=-(\alpha-C)\cdot T^\prime=-(\alpha-c)\cdot\kappa\nu N$

$\kappa(\alpha-C)\cdot N=-1$

So the component of $\alpha-C$ along N is $-\frac{1}{\kappa}=-\rho$

$\frac{d}{dt}||\alpha-C||^2=2(\alpha-C)\cdot T=0$

$\alpha$ is a linear combination of $B$ and $N$.

$\kappa^\prime(\alpha-C)\cdot N=-\kappa(\alpha-C)N^\prime=-\kappa(\alpha-C)\cdot(-\kappa \nu T+\tau B)=-\kappa(\alpha-C)\cdot \tau \nu B$

$(\alpha-C)\cdot B=-\frac{\kappa^\prime(\alpha-C)\cdot N}{\kappa\nu\tau}=\frac{\kappa^\prime}{\kappa^2\nu\tau}$

$(\alpha-C)\cdot B=-\frac{\kappa^\prime}{\kappa^2\nu\tau}=-\frac{\rho^\prime}{\nu\tau}=-\frac{\rho^\prime\sigma}{\nu}$

This is the component of $\alpha-C$ along $B$

$\alpha-c=-\rho N-\frac{\rho^\prime\sigma}{\nu} B$

So for the curve to lie on a sphere, $||\alpha-c||^2=\rho^2+(\frac{\rho^\prime\sigma}{\nu})^2$ is constant and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after going through the derivation and extending it for arbitrary speed, it becomes clear that rather than multiplying by the speed, one has to *divide* by the speed where the derivative appears. Perhaps this should be obvious from the equation $\frac{d\rho}{ds}=\frac{\frac{d\rho}{dt}}{\frac{ds}{dt}}$

Answer (score 0):

There’s no need for unit speed: any Frenet curve $c$ with non-vanishing torsion $\tau$ and curvature $\kappa$ lies on a sphere with center $p$ and radius $r$, that is satisfying $\|c-p\|^2=r^2$, iff
$$
\left(\frac{1}{\kappa}\right)^2+   \left(\left(\frac{1}{\kappa}\right)'\right)^2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right)^2=r^2.$$

Comment: According to my calculations, this formula needs to be modified to take into account the speed. A curve lies on a sphere if $(\frac{1}{\kappa})^2+((\frac{1}{\kappa})^\prime)^2(\frac{1}{\nu})^2\cdot(\frac{1}{\tau})^2$ constant.

Comment: This formula does assume arclength parametrization (because of the differentiation).

Comment: No, it doesn’t.  If $c$ is a Frenet-curve satisfying $\|c-p\|=r^2$, then $c=p_0-\frac{1}{\kappa}N-\left(\frac{1}{\kappa}\right)'\cdot\frac{1}{\tau}\cdot B,$
where $N$ and $B$ denote the normal and binormal vector, resp. From here the formula follows.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: No, there's a factor of $\|c'\|$ in the denominator of the coefficient of $B$.